# C++ Console Application checkboxes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console-application

I am writing a console application in visual studio c++ and want to make a checkbox like in this c# [application](https://github.com/LarsVomMars/Checkboxes).

[image: Snapshot]

Is there any similar solution for C++?

Comment: Have a look at [pdcurses](https://pdcurses.org/) library.  I'm sure about the checkboxes support, but you can do lots of interesting things using this library.

Comment: A checkbox in a console application??? :-)

Comment: @Dominique Why not? I remember a variety of console applications (uhm... at least, in the past), and they provided check boxes. The Unicode contains nice dingbats for this like e.g. `✓✔✕✖✗✘` which can be used on the console (maybe) but a simple `X` or `*` might do as well.

Comment: I don't know such library, but if you want to implement this in your code, you need to use platform-specific _kbhit function. C# application from your link uses Console.KeyAvailable which is actually _kbhit wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create a minimal solution with the _kbhit function from Alex F comment.

I am just printing out the console every time some chnage is made. Right before the printing I am clearing the console. With _khbit I am checking if the user is pressing one of the correct keyboard input. If a checkbox is checked or not, i am saving inside a vector. (Works only on windows!)

checkbox.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using namespace std::this_thread; // sleep_for, sleep_until
using namespace std::chrono; // nanoseconds, system_clock, seconds
using namespace std;

#define KEY_UP 72
#define KEY_DOWN 80
#define KEY_LEFT 75
#define KEY_RIGHT 77
#define KEY_W 119
#define KEY_S 115
#define KEY_ENTER 13
#define KEY_SPACE 32

class Checkbox
{
public:
    ~Checkbox();
    Checkbox(string headline, std::vector<string> lineText);
    std::vector<int> run();
private:
    string headline;
    int lineCount;
    unsigned int line = 0;
    std::vector<int> checkboxesValue;
    std::vector<string> checkboxesText;
    int counter;
    bool finish = false;
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    void processInput(uint8_t input);
    char getInput();
    void tickLine();
    void printLines();
};
```

checkbox.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "checkbox.h"

Checkbox::Checkbox(string headline, std::vector<string> lineText)
{
    this->headline = headline;
    this->checkboxesText = lineText;
    this->lineCount = lineText.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lineText.size(); i++)
    {
        this->checkboxesValue.push_back(0);
    }
}


Checkbox::~Checkbox()
{
}

std::vector<int> Checkbox::run()
{
    printLines();
    while (1)
    {
        while (!_kbhit())
        {
        }
        processInput(_getch());
        printLines();
        if (finish)
        {
            return checkboxesValue;
        }
    }
}

void Checkbox::processInput(uint8_t input)
{
    switch (input) {
    case KEY_UP:
    case KEY_W:
        // W and up key: up
        line = line - 1;
        if (line == -1)
        {
            line = lineCount -1;
        }
        break;
    case KEY_DOWN:
    case KEY_S:
        // S and down key: down
        line = (line + 1) % lineCount;
        break;
    case KEY_ENTER:
        // enter
        finish = true;
        break;
    case KEY_SPACE:
        // space: select
        tickLine();
        break;
    }
}

char Checkbox::getInput()
{
    while (!_kbhit())
    {
    }
    char input = _getch();
    return input;
}

void Checkbox::tickLine()
{
    if (checkboxesValue[line])
    {
        checkboxesValue[line] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        checkboxesValue[line] = 1;
    }
}

void Checkbox::printLines()
{
    system("cls");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 7);
    cout << headline.c_str() << endl;
    cout << "(Use arrow keys to navigate up and down, space bar to select and enter to submit.)" << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < checkboxesValue.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i == line)
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 4);
        }
        else
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 7);
        }
        cout << "[";
        if (checkboxesValue[i])
        {
            cout << "x";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "] " << checkboxesText[i].c_str() << endl;
    }
}
```

To use it just provide a vector of string and it will return a vector of int, with either 0 (not checked) or 1 (checked).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "checkbox.h"
#include <string> 
int main()
{
    std::vector<string> lineTexts;
    lineTexts.push_back("first line");
    lineTexts.push_back("second line");
    lineTexts.push_back("third line");
    string headline = "Choose one of the following";

    Checkbox checkbox(headline, lineTexts);
    std::vector<int> result = checkbox.run();

    cout << "Checkboxes: " << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "line " << i << " " << result[i] << endl;
    }
}
```